# SQL Alchemy(core) row value expression

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

How can I generate row value expressions(https://www.dummies.com/programming/sql/how-to-use-sql-row-value-expressions/) using SQL alchemy core?

```sql
select some_num, some_id where (some_num, some_id) > (5, '462eb1f5-0ac4-41df-876c-88705174808c') from some_table
```

I've tried things like this:

```py
this_condition = ((sprints.c.sprint_seq, sprints.c.id) > (params.sprint_seq, marker))
```

Also couldn't find anything on "row value expressions" in sqlalchemy documentation...

Hopefully some wizard can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the term I was looking for was "row-wise comparison" in the postgres world. For those who end up here in the future: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#table-values-row-and-tuple-objects